# How do I get the current absolute URL in a class in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a library from which I want to access this controller method:

```
 request.original_url
```

In order to have the absolute url of my project. I already tried with:

```
 include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers
 link = url_for :controller => 'things', :action => 'download', :host => 'http://abc/'
```

But it requires to specify host, so it doesn't works for me.

Comment: So you need to get the URL inside a library? Can you pass it to whatever is calling the library method?

Comment: Can you explain a little broader what are you trying to do?